# Charging Capacitor with grounded terminal

Tags: capacitance

I had a question about the charging of a parallel plate capacitor. Let's assume the following situation: we connect the negative terminal of the battery and one of the capacitor plates to ground. The positive terminal connects directly to the plate as in the figure. I understand that the negative terminal and the plate will be at the same potential (gnd) and there should be no flow of electrons. So the grounded plate never becomes negatively charged?
[image]

Comment: Why wouldn’t it? Replace ground with a wire…

Comment: It's hard to begin to respond to this. The positive battery terminal and plate connected to it are, assuming a zero resistance wire, at the same potential aren't they. And won't current flow between them? Two points having the same potential doesn't mean electrons can't flow between them.  In any case, the negative terminal and plate are not at the same potential since you have indicated resistance in the soil.

Comment: Ok, I started to get confused with the following paragraph from Serway's book: "...Let us focus on the plate connected to the negative terminal of the battery. The
electric field applies a force on electrons in the wire just outside this plate; this
force causes the electrons to move onto the plate. This movement continues until
the plate, the wire, and the terminal are all at the same electric potential. Once this
equilibrium point is attained, a potential difference no longer exists between the
terminal and the plate..."

Comment: @BobD How will electrons flow if there is no electric field to move them? If a conductor is an equipotential, then there is no tangential component of $\vec E$. The kind of flow we are talking about here is not thermal diffusion, etc.

Comment: @AlbertusMagnus don’t electrons flow through a superconductor?

Comment: Granted BobD, however, superconducting seems a bit far removed from the contex of this post.

Comment: @AlbertusMagnus All I’m saying is an electric field (potential difference) doesn’t theoretically need to exist to have current. In circuits we assume current flowing in zero resistance wires all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you have a couple of misconceptions.

1. You say the negative battery terminal and plate are at the same potential, yet you've drawn resistance in the soil between them which means they are not, in fact, at the same potential.
2. You seem to think there can't be current flow if two points ***are*** at the same potential, yet you seem to accept that current will flow between the positive terminal and plate which are at the same potential (if we assume a zero wire resistance).

In circuits we generally assume zero resistance wires (wires where there is no potential difference along them) with current flowing through them (though all real conductors, with the exception of superconductors, have some resistance).

That said, in the circuit you've drawn it is certainly possible to charge the capacitor using a return path through the Earth. The rate of charging will depend on the total resistance between the negative battery terminal and capacitor plate. That, in turn, will depend on  soil resistivity, the type of electrodes (the conductors inserted into the soil), the distance between electrodes, and the length of the electrode in contact with the soil.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank Bob. I began to get confused with the following paragraph from Serway's book that speaks as if there were potential difference on each side of the circuit (e.g., between the negative terminal and negative plate): "...Let us focus on the plate connected to the negative terminal of the battery. The electric field applies a force on electrons in the wire just outside this plate; this force causes the electrons to move onto the plate. This movement continues until the plate, the wire, and the terminal are all at the same electric potential..."

Comment: @BobD Interesting way you have of thinking about the lines on schematics as "zero resistance wires", I have always just thought of them as statements about what is connected to what; always having the current flow through actual components with resistance. All amounts to the same thing, of course, I intend no criticism of your methods.

Comment: @AlbertusMagnus No problem. Never taken as criticism.

Comment: @GabrielDiez I think I see the source of your confusion. Serway is saying the electric field is moving electrons to the plate through the soil  WHILE the capacitor is charging. During that time there is a potential difference between the negative battery terminal and plate due to the voltage drop across the soil. That's the condition I was referring to in my answer. But once the capacitor is charged the current stops and there is no longer a potential difference between the negative battery terminal and plate.

Comment: Yes, I think I understand Serway now. Let's assume a 12V battery. While the capacitor is charging, in the capacitor let's assume a drop of 10V, then I can have a difference of 1V (12V - 11V) between the positive terminal and the positive plate, and 1V (1V - 0V) difference between the negative plate and the negative terminal. This will continue until "...the plate, the wire, and the terminal are all at the same electric potential...". Do you see it well? Thank you.

Comment: I’m confused. Is the voltage drop across the capacitor 10V or 11V? Whatever it is, it is the potential drop across the soil . There is no potential difference between the positive terminal and positive plate if we assume zero resistance in the wire connecting the two

Comment: Sorry, from my last comment I am assuming that there is no resistance to ground and that there is resistance in the wires. The voltage drop across the capacitor is 10V.

Comment: Your assumptions are unrealistic

Comment: I don't think I explained myself well. I don't want to assume that the ground has no resistance, instead, that in my circuit it doesn't connect to ground. That is, the negative part is connected directly by wires like the positive part. In this case there would be no more resistant than those of the wires, and the internal one of the battery.

Comment: Then why did you provide a drawing with ground? I’m sorry but this is getting so confusing I’m afraid I have no more time to devote to it. Good luck and I hope you get the answer you’re looking for

Answer (score 1):

There will electrons flow to the grounded plate, it just takes some time till it reaches  almost the same potential as the negative plate. You can find the equation for the time flow in any physics book.

Comment: But what potential does the negative plate have to reach? In my figure, the plate is already grounded as is the negative terminal, aren't they at the same potential from the beginning?

Answer (score 1):

The negative terminal and ground are not the same thing, but they are often connected.
The ground is a common reference charge level across the circuit. It is often most negative than the other charge levels and therefore often connected to the negative terminal of a battery.
When you use the negative terminal of the battery as a "ground" it is really just the common node (return) of the circuit. Using the negative terminal ensures that all of the components have an identical reference point.